# Should I us "is" or "are" with "there"?

Tags: grammatical-number, existentials, compound-subjects

Which of the following two sentences is correct?

> There ***is*** one primary station and multiple secondary stations.
>
> There ***are*** one primary station and multiple secondary stations.

I think the first one is correct. But I don't know the reason.

Comment: Piyush, both of them are correct. Please refer here for more discussion https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140854/there-is-there-are-depends-on-plurality-of-the-first-list-element-or-not/140863#140863

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first one is correct. Often we have the verb match the closest subject, and elide the other.

So the bold here would be a correct sentence, and the brackets contain the implied verb:

> **There is one primary station and** *[there are]* **multiple secondary stations.**
>
> **There is one over here and** *[there is]* **one over there**.
>
> **There are three stations nearby and** *[there is]* **one further away**.